# Window Context Sub Menu in Dialog

Tags: vb.net, windows, shell, contextmenu

I've created an application to help maintain folder/file path formatting to be used around the office. When the exe is initially run in administrator mode, the application adds registry entities to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\shell\PathStructure` path and sub items to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\`, where **PathStructure** is the name of the application and the sub items are keyed with `PathStructure.*` with * replaced with the command name.

This works completely fine when navigating the Windows explorer and the commands work as expected. However, when navigating through a open or save dialog only the root menu item **Path Structure** is displayed and the sub menu will not cascade in non-Microsoft applications. A good example of a submenu that always works is the **Send to** menu item which properly cascades in every dialog I've tested.

Here's an example of trying to save (left) and navigating Explorer (right):
[image: Saving vs. Exploring]

Here's an example of a sub item registry entity (from CommandStore):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\PathStructure.Add.All]
"MUIVerb"="Create All main folders"
"icon"="%windir%\\system32\\shell32.dll,278"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\PathStructure.Add.All\command]
@="\"\\\\{Network Path}\\Path Structure Maintenance.exe\" -addall \"%1\""
```

Here's the registry entity for the main node:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\PathStructure]
"MUIVerb"="Path Structure"
"SubCommands"="PathStructure.Open;PathStructure.Add;PathStructure.Format;PathStructure.Audit;PathStructure.Clipboard;PathStructure.TransferByExtension;PathStructure.Preview;"
"icon"="%windir%\\system32\\imageres.dll,153"
```

Am I missing any parameters that could allow me to access the submenu through a dialog? Are my sub items in the wrong part of the registry? Or am I better off diving into developing a Context Handler?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 64-bit version of Windows, try adding your custom entries to this key, as well:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\CommandStore\shell